# Principal ideal of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $ I = \langle 5x^2 \rangle$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Let $J_{x+1} = {\{f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] : f(x)\cdot(x+1) \in I}\}$. How do I find out what this ideal is?

I assume for a polynomial $g(x)$ to be in $I$ it would have to be divisible by $5x^2$, so if we looked at $J_x$, then $f(x)$ would have to be divisible by $5x$, and so $J_x = \langle 5x \rangle$.

I can’t seem to figure out what $J_{x+1}$ is though? My intution tells me it is $I$ but I’m not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it as the polynomial $f(x)$ multiplied by the polynomial $x+1$

Comment: I see. Yes that is standard notation, but it's much better with the dot. Thanks. I'll tidy away my comment.

Comment: Do you need the subscripts $x$ and $x+1$ on $J$? Does $J_x$ depend on $x$ in some way?

Comment: The subscript is for the polynomial which is multiplied by $f(x)$. For example, $J_x = {\{f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] : f(x) \cdot x \in I}\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, for $g \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$, you are defining:

$$
J_g = \{ f \in \Bbb{Z}[x] : fg \in I\}
$$

where $I$ is the ideal $\langle 5x^2 \rangle$ and you want to know what $J_g$ is when $g = x + 1$. (Here I am writing $f$ where you write $f(x)$ as is standard in this context: we don't need a continual reminder that $f$ is a polynomial in the indeterminate $x$.)

Now, $f \cdot (x+1) \in I$ iff there is $h \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that:

$$
f \cdot (x + 1) = h \cdot 5x^2
$$

but $x + 1$ is irreducible and it is not a factor of $5x^2$ (as you can check by polynomial division), so if the above equation holds, $x + 1$ is a factor of $h$ (using the fact that $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a unique factorisation domain). I.e., we have
$$
h = h_0 \cdot (x + 1)
$$
for some $h_0 \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ and then we have
$$
f = h_0 \cdot 5x^2
$$
implying that $f \in I$.

Comment: Actually we don't need any deep results since evaluating at $\,x = -1\,$ shows $5h(-1) = 0$ so $h(-1) = 0$ so $\,x+1\mid h\,$ by the Factor Theorem.

Comment: @BillDubuque: sure. My preference was for an argument that generalises to deal with any irreducible $g$.

Comment: As mine, but I mentioned that in case the OP may not yet have access to the result that it is a UFD (or, equivalently, irreducibles are prime).

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)f\in (5x^2)\iff 5x^2\mid (x+1)f\iff 5x^2\mid f\,$ since $5,x$ are primes not dividing the prime $x+1$ (equivalently use unique prime factorization).